# How to solve error 'self.floatingGroupRowView should be equal to the given row view!'?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

My macOS app uses a NSTableView with 'Floats Group Row' enabled. This works without problems on my test Macs. However, on a regular basis I receive crash reports from users with:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'self.floatingGroupRowView should be equal to the given row view!'`

Does anyone know the conditions for this error?

The last part of the crashlog look similar to this:

> 0   CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff51db6ff3 __exceptionPreprocess + 147
>   1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x00007fff78992c76 objc_exception_throw + 48
>   2   CoreFoundation                       0x00007fff51dbcda2 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
>   3   Foundation                           0x00007fff53ebb260 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 192
>   4   AppKit                               0x00007fff4f656e9f -[NSTableRowData _updateFloatingGroupRowView:row:] + 421
>   5   AppKit                               0x00007fff4f4245db -[NSTableRowData _updateFrameRowView:row:] + 100
>   6   AppKit                               0x00007fff4fd03fca __48-[NSTableRowData _doAutomaticRowHeightsForRows:]_block_invoke.1004 + 47
>   7   AppKit                               0x00007fff4f40eae2 -[NSTableRowData enumerateAvailableRowViewsUsingBlock:] + 139
>   8   AppKit                               0x00007fff4fd03ede -[NSTableRowData _doAutomaticRowHeightsForRows:] + 274
>   9   AppKit                               0x00007fff4fd07157 __59-[NSTableRowData _automaticRowHeightsUpdateVisibleRowViews]_block_invoke.1494 + 141
>   10  AppKit                               0x00007fff4fd06d05 -[NSTableRowData _keepTopRowStable:andDoWorkUntilDone:] + 535
>   11  AppKit                               0x00007fff4fd07075 -[NSTableRowData _automaticRowHeightsUpdateVisibleRowViews] + 161
>   12  AppKit                               0x00007fff4f415d85 -[NSTableRowData updateVisibleRowViews] + 261
>   13  AppKit                               0x00007fff4f5bf24e -[NSTableRowData prepareContentInRect:] + 106
>   14  AppKit                               0x00007fff4f5bed46 -[NSTableView prepareContentInRect:] + 303
>   15  AppKit                               0x00007fff4fbbf7b1 __38-[NSView _pullInExtraTilesForOverdraw]_block_invoke + 562
>   16  AppKit                               0x00007fff4f484a19 -[NSView _performWorkOnTilesFromRect:renderedContentRect:maximumRect:scrollVelocity:handler:] + 1544
>   17  AppKit                               0x00007fff4f4841f2 -[NSView _pullInExtraTilesForOverdraw] + 854
>   18  AppKit                               0x00007fff4f483e6d -[NSView _doIdlePrefetch] + 37

Unfortunately, these crashlogs don't point consistently to one particular line in my code.

Comment: Do you use custom row views or custom row heights?

Comment: @Willeke, yes. Regarding the row height, I use the new usesAutomaticRowHeights property when running macOS 10.13. All crash logs are from macOS 10.13...